# MongoDB aggregation on another aggreatation suggestions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `Json` file imported into `MongoDB`. Every line on it is a user, and I have a field product, with the name of it. I know the value of every product, they are just few. 
But this information is not stored on the `Json`.

I was able to do aggregation to retrieve the number of time that a user bought a product, but I would like to do a query to get directly the amount of money that each user spent.

This is my query:

```js
db.source.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
       "$and":[
           {"productName":{
               "$in":[
                    "product2","product2","product3",
                    "product4","product5","product6"
                   ]
           }}, 
           { "$or": [
               {"appID" : "nameOfAPP"},
               {"appID": "NameOfAPP2"}
           ]}
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "id_user": "$id_user", 
            "productName": "$productName"
        }, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1}
    }},
    { "$sort" : { "count": -1 } }
])
```

so the output is like that:

```js
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user1", "productID" : "product2" }, "count" : 433 }
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user2", "productID" : "product1" }, "count" : 370 }
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user1", "productID" : "product3" }, "count" : 300 }
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user3", "productID" : "product6" }, "count" : 250 }
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user2", "productID" : "product5" }, "count" : 140 }
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user3", "productID" : "product4" }, "count" : 90 }
```

I know that product 1 costs 20$, product 2 costs 40$, product 3 costs 55$, product 4 costs -90$, product 5 costs 110$, product 6 costs 200$.

I would like to have an output like that:

```js
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user1"}, "money_spent" : 600$ }
{ "_id" : { "id_user" : "user2"}, "money_spent" : 400$ }
etc
```

Can you help to get that result, I am new with `MongoDB`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using MongoDB console to achieve above result or what!!!

Comment: yeah MongoDB console :)

Comment: @user3702916 maybe a stupid question, but do you have the cost stored in the same document?

Comment: Can you actually post your first aggregation to get to the input you are aggregating again. I'd be fairly sure you only need a single pipeline and not `$out` to a collection and aggregate again

Comment: And your source document structure as well.

Comment: Please refer - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: @Christian P : No I don't have the cost stored in a document, I just know it.

Comment: @Neil Lunn I'm not sure it needs another aggregation. Anyway this is structure of the json file that I've imported:
{"id_user":"user1", productName:"product1" and many others}
{"id_user":"user3", productName:"product2" and many others}
{"id_user":"user2", productName:"product6" and many others}

Comment: @user3702916 It seems as if an additional aggregation is required by what you are grouping on. Your title suggests that the output comes from another aggregation operation, which is why I suggest the original source document and not the import. You are also suggesting output of fields that are not clearly stated as being in your source. I am just trying to help here and not jump to answers in a bid to score points. So the more information you can provide the better your responses will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot go to the original source data an are only working with an import then do this:

```js
db.source.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
       "$and":[
           { "productName": {
               "$in":[
                    "product1","product2","product3",
                    "product4","product5","product6"
                   ]
           }}, 
           { "$or": [
               {"appID" : "nameOfAPP"},
               {"appID": "NameOfAPP2"}
           ]}
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$id_user",
       "cost": {
           "$sum": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": ["$_id.productId", "product1"] },
                   20,
                   { "$cond": [
                       { "$eq": ["$productName", "product2"] },
                       40,
                       { "$cond": [
                           { "$eq": [ "$productName", "product3"] },
                           55,
                           { "$cond": [
                               { "$eq": [ "$productName", "product4" ] },
                               -90,
                               { "$cond": [ 
                                   { "$eq": [ "$productName", "product5" ] },
                                   110,
                                   200
                               ]}
                           ]}
                       ]}             
                   ]}
               }
           }
       }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator evaluates whether your field value matches the condition and places the appropriate value simply just [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to get your result.

[**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) provides a "ternary" operator or *"if .. then .. else"* that is used to evaluate the condition you provide in the first argument. You construct this to "cascade" where the condition evaluates to `false` in order to move on to the next condition to evaluate, otherwise return the value that matches your condition.

In this way your "known" values are applied as you aggregate for your expected total.